# Magento2: While installing theme static-content:deploy after deploy got blank screen

Tags: magento-2.1, error, theme, installation, static-content-deploy

Using a paid theme for Magento 2.1.X, according to the theme user guide followed all the instructions to place the necessary files in Magento root, when I try to execute all the shell command that worked fine, after that store IP and admin link displaying a white screen, leave me clueless.

STORE IP:  http://52.187.32.74/testdata/

ADMIN IP:  http://52.187.32.74/testdata/admin_testdata/

Answer (score 1):

Try run:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

This will also run `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy`.
In few of my cases I got similar problem with manual run of static content deploy.